# Función no recibe array como parámetro de forma correcta en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

Tengo un código que pide por `prompt` 5 valores, que se los pasa a una primera función y esta, a su vez los pasa a una segunda función que debe devolver el valor más alto y el índice del array con el valor más bajo.

Mediante un `console.log` compruebo que el array ha recibido correctamente los valores introducidos, sin embargo, al usar el método `Math.max()` con el array, el `console.log` correspondiente me devuelve `NaN`.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Estoy pasando bien los parámetros de una función a la otra? Tras muchas comprobaciones parece que ahí está el error, pero logro distinguirlo.
Muchas gracias.

```js
function mainFunction(){
      "use strict";

      let i = 1;
      const severalNumbers = [];

      while (i<=5){

          severalNumbers.push(parseFloat(prompt("Introcuce un número", ""))); // Validar que se trata de un número
          i++
      }  

      document.getElementById("resultB").innerHTML = "El índice del valor más pequeño introducido es " + numbersArray(severalNumbers);

      console.log(severalNumbers, i);
}


function numbersArray(severalNumbers){
      "use strict";

      let maxNumber;

      maxNumber = Math.max(severalNumbers);
      console.log(maxNumber);

      // console.log(Math.max(severalNumbers)); // pasa por consola el valor máximo del array

      console.log(Math.max(severalNumbers), Math.min(severalNumbers));
      return severalNumbers.indexOf(Math.min(severalNumbers)); // return > la posición del valor mínimo del array
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3 FUNCIONES</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Working With Functions</h2>
    <p>First let's invoke the main function...</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="mainFunction()" value="I SUMMON YOU !!!">
    <p id="resultB"></p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Nota: aunque usar dos funciones no sea la manera óptimade de solucionar este problema, se trata de un ejercicio. Tras muchas comprobaciones, me encallo siempre en el mismo punto. En el código hay comentarios y otras funciones que resuleven parte del enunciado.

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna de las respuestas, no olvides marcarla como aceptada y darle un voto positivo, así otros usuarios con problemas similares sabrán cuál fue la solución.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te fijás en la documentación de MDN de [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) y [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min), te vas a percatar de que para los arrays se utiliza [la sintaxis *spread* (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

> *Spread* en este caso podría traducirse como *de propagación*.

```js
function mainFunction(){
      "use strict";

      let i = 1;
      const severalNumbers = [];

      while (i<=5){

          severalNumbers.push(parseFloat(prompt("Introcuce un número", ""))); // Validar que se trata de un número
          i++
      }  

      document.getElementById("resultB").innerHTML = "El índice del valor más pequeño introducido es " + numbersArray(severalNumbers);

      console.log(severalNumbers, i);
}


function numbersArray(severalNumbers){
      "use strict";

      let maxNumber;

      maxNumber = Math.max(...severalNumbers);
      console.log(maxNumber);

      // console.log(Math.max(severalNumbers)); // pasa por consola el valor máximo del array

      console.log(Math.max(...severalNumbers), Math.min(...severalNumbers));
      return severalNumbers.indexOf(Math.min(severalNumbers)); // return > la posición del valor mínimo del array
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3 FUNCIONES</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Working With Functions</h2>
    <p>First let's invoke the main function...</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="mainFunction()" value="I SUMMON YOU !!!">
    <p id="resultB"></p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vaya, eso no lo ví!  Y estaba tan solo una linea más abajo en la documentación! :-)  Me gusta mas tu solución, queda más elegante

Comment: Ponele que es "más corta" también :)

Answer (score 1):

Estas intentando pasar un *array* a [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) y [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) cuando esas funciones esperan una serie de valores separados por comas:

> Sintaxis
>
> Math.max([valor1[, valor2[, ...]]])

Una forma correcta de pasarles un array seria esta:

```
Math.max.apply(null, array)
Math.min.apply(null, array)
```

Aquí te dejo un snippet funcionando con dicho cambio:

```js
function mainFunction() {
  "use strict";

  let i = 1;
  const severalNumbers = [];

  while (i <= 5) {

    severalNumbers.push(parseFloat(prompt("Introcuce un número", ""))); // Validar que se trata de un número
    i++
  }

  document.getElementById("resultB").innerHTML = "El índice del valor más pequeño introducido es " + numbersArray(severalNumbers);

  console.log(severalNumbers, i);
}


function numbersArray(severalNumbers) {
  "use strict";

  let maxNumber;

  maxNumber = Math.max.apply(null, severalNumbers);
  console.log(maxNumber);

  // console.log(Math.max(severalNumbers)); // pasa por consola el valor máximo del array

  console.log(Math.max.apply(null, severalNumbers), Math.min.apply(null, severalNumbers));
  return severalNumbers.indexOf(Math.min(severalNumbers)); // return > la posición del valor mínimo del array
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3 FUNCIONES</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h2>Working With Functions</h2>
    <p>First let's invoke the main function...</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="mainFunction()" value="I SUMMON YOU !!!">
    <p id="resultB"></p>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Donde dices `Match.max` quieres decir `Math.max`, verdad?

Comment: @IvanSanczewski Arreglado, gracias por el aporte!